AWS Lamba Accessing S3 Bucket
Im trying to upload an image into my S3 bucket from a live site using AWM Amplify
but i keep getting this error in my cloudfront:
ERROR Error in headObject: Forbidden: null.
I know its a permission issue but ive looked online and applied what everyones been saying but i still keep getting that issue.
In my lambda function i click on configuration, and the rolename. Inside my role i created a inline policy named S3Access:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Trust relationship:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}


Then i go in my S3 Bucket and i make this my policy:
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::32132131241:distribution/EKTT2sAWYDZ"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowLambdaFunctionAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/awsLambdaRole312d22e0a-auth"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Am i missing something here?

Side-note: You don't need to include the Lambda function in your Bucket Policy since the IAM Role on the Lambda function already permits it access to the bucket. There is no need to grant permission via BOTH the IAM Role and the Bucket Policy -- either is sufficient. However, this seems unrelated to the error you are receiving.

The error seems to be saying the CloudFront is not permitted to access the bucket. Granting s3:GetObject should be sufficient for a HeadObject request, and this is what your Bucket Policy is doing. Are you able to access an object directly (rather than via Amplify) when going via CloudFront? For example, put an object in the bucket and then try to access it via the CloudFront distribution's URL.

It was unable to access the object in my S3 bucket, i changed the setting so that now the url works correctly and am able to fetch the Image with the url. But im still getting that error.
Access Denied in headObject: Forbidden: null
at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:692:35)
sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
code: 'Forbidden',
region: null,
time: 2024-06-13T19:48:35.563Z,
}

Can you show us the code you are using in the Lambda function to upload the object to the S3 bucket? The Lambda function should be uploading the object direct to S3 without involving CloudFront, yet your error message mentions CloudFront. Something doesn't seem right there.
